Practice test paper answers all seem incorrect, but provider insists they are ... what am i missing?
I bought some math practice papers for my 10yr old in preparation for UK 11+ exam. He got frustrated by one of the questions because none of the provided answers seem correct. I agree with him, but i've contacted the provider and they have insisted (twice) that the correct answer is 200 minutes. I get 400 minutes, which is not one of the multiple-choice answers provided. What am I missing?
Here is the question:

Joe caught a train from Glasgow to Manchester. It arrived in Manchester 15 minutes early although it had set off from Glasgow 5 minutes late.
The journey took 19/20 of the time it should have done.
How long should the train journey have been?
A. 180 minutes
B. 300 minutes
C. 190 minutes
D. 200 minutes
E. 240 minutes


pay them half, they wont tell the difference

Being a serious guy Joe was already in his seat at the scheduled departure time. Since then train only left 5 mins later, Joe assumed he would arrive 5 mins too late, but to his surprise the train caught up by 15 minutes, ie. arrived 10 minutes before schedule. So altogether Joe saved 10 minutes, so for him the travel time was 190mins out of the scheduled 200. Ta-dam. (This is not a serious answer).

You are talking to a bureaucracy, which will never check if it is wrong and will always keep insisting that you are wrong, then stop communicating at all.

The question is unambigous, and the correct answer is definitely 400 minutes.

They subtracted 15 and 5 when they should have added them, that's it.

All the information is only there to distract you ("how old is the driver?"). The correct answer, which is clearly documented in the train schedule, is 3h15m, or 195 minutes nominal. Unfortunately, this is also not one of the options.

The ambiguity appears to be in what 15 minutes early means.

If it is 15 minutes earlier than the train was scheduled to arrive, then on top of the 5 minutes late departure that is a total of 20 minutes less time and hence the answer 400 minutes.

On the other hand, if it is 15 minutes early compared to the adjusted expectation set when leaving five minutes late, then that would be a journey 10 minutes early in the usual sense. However the journey time in this case would actually be 15 minutes less, hence the answer should be 300 minutes.

Though if you count the 5 minutes before the train leaves as journey time, you would then get 10 minutes less of the journey, giving 200 minutes.


For example, suppose a one hour journey is planned to set off at 11, and arrive at 12. Instead it leaves at 11:05 and now expects to arrive at 12:05. If it then arrives fifteen minutes before this, it is now 11:50 which is therefore 10 minutes early in some strange sense.
To be honest, I got the same answer as the OP when I first tried.

There is no ambiguity. In the context of train arrivals, early/late always means with respect to the original scheduled time. If your train starts 40 minutes late but saves 5 minutes en route, it still arrived 35 minutes late and you are entitled to compensation.

I agree @EspeciallyLime, I am just trying to reverse engineer the other solution.

I don't think that's how they got it - the word "although" in particular makes it sound like they intend the normal meaning of "early". It is IMO far more likely that the question got changed in the course of writing (perhaps it was originally 9/10 instead of 19/20) and the answers didn't. In fact, it looks very much like they got as far as changing A and B but not the later options, which is why they aren't in order.

That is quite possible, I think.

This is the sort of thing that genuinely does happen but gets spotted before the question goes live. Practice papers might not get checked as carefully as live papers, especially if they are being produced by a company that doesn't set the actual paper.

thanks all, good points ...

I think the ambiguity is in "journey" - as in, is it from boarding the train just before departure to alighting at destination, or is it from the point in time the train starts moving to the time it comes to rest? The former seems the more natural to me - as in, if the train left on time but then stopped en route for 5 minutes, you wouldn't deduct that 5 minutes from the "journey time" even though functionally it's much the same as leaving the station 5 late - Joe still had to be on board at the scheduled departure time.

There are three approaches to this question.

The train set off $5$ minutes later and arrived $15$ minutes earlier, so it did the journey in $20$ minutes less. Therefore it should have taken $400$ minutes.

Joe did the journey in $15$ minutes less than he should. (For the first $5$ minutes he was stationary, but that doesn't save any time.) Therefore he should have taken $300$ minutes.

Checking the National Rail website, the next few trains from Glasgow to Manchester take between 3 hr 17 min and 3 hr 22 min. So the answer must be $200$ minutes.


IMO it is unreasonable to expect someone to find solution #3 under exam conditions.

Yes, I agree, 300 minutes is the more correct answer for the journey time that question actually asks for, but then the "departs 5 minutes late" makes it a trick question because it is unnecessary information designed to force you into a mistake.

It's not a trick question -- the meaning is clear and unambiguous. They just got their sums wrong -- the answer is 400 minutes.

+1 for checking the actual travel time! I assume that's why someone picked 200 minutes as the correct answer in the first place (but then they, or someone else, changed the question in a way that made that answer no longer match the problem statement, probably by replacing 9/10 with 19/20 or something like that).

@TonyK no, it's not a trick question. But I agree with Stevie that if the intended answer had been 300, that would make it one.
